# JSON list of objects

Tags: json, delphi

I have this JSON:

```json
{ "Map":
  { "AM": 
    { "n": "Armenia" 
    }
  , "AR": 
    { "n": "Argentina" 
    }
  , "AU": 
    { "n": "Australia" 
    }
  , "BG": 
    { "n": "Bulgaria" 
    }
  }
}
```

and I have two classes:

```delphi
type 
  TMap= Class
    Fn: String;
  end;
    
  Tkop= class
    FMap= array of TMap;
  end;
```

I am trying:

```delphi
var 
  kop: Tkop;
  json: String;
begin
  kop:= TJson.JsonToObject<TKop>(json);
```

It's not working because this is a list of objects and not an array of objects. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: i dotn think delphi can do this.You need to parse it manually

Comment: I am trying to avoid the manual parsing. Maybe there is a method with rest Json like when parsing array of objects.

Comment: You don't have list of objects (that is basically having array of objects). You have dictionary where strings are keys and TMap are values.  Your FMap should be dictionary and not an array. Another problem you will have is configuring JSON framework to correctly parse dictionary from the format you have.